# Array type: text simple_form Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I have an array type in my model.

This is my migration:

```
add_column :products, :weekdays, :text, array:true, default: []
```

Could I use it as a simple form...

```
= simple_form_for @product do |f|
  = f.input :weekdays
```

Somebody knows how is the best way to use it??

Comment: `weekdays` suggest that the array is practically an array of enum , is it ?

Comment: yes, This is just an example... For instance an array of integers... What do you think??

Comment: I think in that solution....

= f.collection_check_boxes :weekdays, weekdays_select, :first, :last

And it is working for me... I don't know if you have a best way

Comment: What is `weekdays_select`? And what would you like to improve about your current solution?

Comment: weekdays_select is an array with the elements to select, for instance: [["Monday", 0]["Tuesday", 1]...]... I don't know if it is the best solution...